# Github Branch Creation Data from API

Tags: git, github, date, api, branch

I want to analyze open source software collaborations. For my purposes I need to get the approximate point in time when a branch was created, even if it was merged afterwards. Is there a way to get this via API? I noticed that gitk can display this information, so apparently it is stored somewhere.

Comment: Have you checked the API documentation to see if/how this info can be accessed?

Comment: yes, there seems to be no direct way of doing this, but maybe there is a trick?